# How to prevent artefacts in transparent images when generating thumbnails?

Tags: thumbnails, shopware, shopware6, image-compression

When generating thumbnails we get these weird artefacts in transparent images.

Original (test) Image (1920x1920):

[image: Original (test) Image (1920x1920)]

360x360 thumbnail:

[image: 360x360 thumbnail]

360x360 thumbnail with boosted contrast to show the issue:

[image: 360x360 thumbnail with increased contrast]

I expect shopware to generate thumbnails and leave the transparent parts transparent. I tried generating thumbnails in a bunch of different sizes with quality at 100%, all suffer from this issue one way or another.

Comment: might be eventually related go GDLib?